# Extract var value from preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to simulate a bbcode tag, like code below:

```
[code]this is code to render[/code]
[code attributeA=arg]this is code to render[/code]
[code attribute C=arg anotherAtributte=anotherArg]this is code to render[/code]
```

As you can see, the code tag can take as many attributes as needed, also could exists too many code tags in the same "publishment". I only have dealed with easiest tags like img, b, a, i. For example:

```
$result = preg_replace('#\[link\=(.+)\](.+)\[\/link\]#iUs', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $publishment);
```

That works fine since it returns the final markup. But, in the code tag I need to have the "attributes" and "values" in array in order to build the markup myselft according to these attributes in order to simulate someting like this:

```
$code_tag = someFunction("[code ??=?? ...] content [/code]", $array );

//build the markup myself
$attribute1 = array_contains("attribute1", $array)? $array["attribute1"] : "";
echo '<pre {$attribute1}>' . $array['content'] . </pre>
```

So, I don't expect that you do it entirely for me, I need you just help to take me to the right direction because I never have used regex.

Thank you in advance

Comment: FYI, if you're using `#` as your delimiter, you don't need to escape your `/` characters in the regex.

Comment: @Matt, those are some little notes that I will keep in mind in futher. =)

Comment: You might want to try parsing for the attribute/value pairs using `preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches)` first. Then `$matches` will be an array of all the matched values.

Comment: @Matt, I have tried your option, but how can I delete the original tag and replace it by my markup? (I mean the workflow)

Comment: that can be done with `preg_replace()` as you've done it, incorporating the `$matches` into the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use preg_replace_callback for such things:

```
function codecb($matches)
{
    $original=$matches[0];
    $parameters=$matches[1];
    $content=$matches[2];
    return "<pre>". $content ."</pre>";
}

preg_replace_callback("#\[code(.*)\](.+)\[\/code\]#iUs", "codecb", $str);
```

so when you have `[code argA=test argB=test]This is content[/code]` then in the function "codecb" you will have:

```
$original = "[code argA=test argB=test]This is content[/code]"
$parameters = " argA=test argB=test"
$content = "This is content"
```

and can `preg_match` the arguments and `return` the replacement for the whole.